# は in いいえ。健康のために少しは外へ出かけてくれたらいいんですが and ご主人にもっと働いてほしいんですか

Tags: grammar

> いいえ。健康のために**少しは**外へ出かけてくれたらいいんですが。 ([source: p 2](https://www.docdroid.net/a1B7uAr/img.pdf.html))

The placement of すこし and the function of すこし as a topic (I guess) kind of makes my head spin. Maybe the は is a contrastive marker? Here's how I would interpret the sentence, or at least the only way I can think of right now

> No. It should be good for the health to give going outside a little.

EDIT: This sentence, page 1 sentence from the very bottom, also puts a few question marks over my head:

> ご主人にもっと働いてほしいんですか。

It is again に that confuses me. I'd rather expect a は or が here to mark ご主人 as topic or at least grammatical subject.
However, I could make sense of it if I was sure that a passive voice is meant here. Like this:

> Is it wished from Mr. Clerk to work more?

Comment: Related: [Does は mean 'at least' in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29438/5010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is quite helpful here.

It seems that the wife is rather bothered with how her husband is currently passing his days.  When she says,

> 何もしないで、家でテレビばかり見てるんですよ。

She's expressing frustration that all he does is watch TV.  So, person A asks,

> いいじゃありませんか。これまで４０年も働いたんですから。
>
> Isn't that OK?  Up until now, he worked for 40 years?

The wife demurs with でも、・・・ to which person A then asks,

> ご主人にもっと働いてほしいんですか。
>
> Is it that you want your husband to work some more?

The grammar here is that of "wanting someone else to do something".  In this situation, the verb is then used in the て-form followed by ほしい to express the idea of "want [someone] to do [something]".  The person **wanting** this is the subject of the sentence and would likely be marked by が/は depending on context.  The **someone** who is wanted to do something is usually going to be marked by に, the particle to show the **agent** of the action.

Back to the story...

So, the wife then responds,

> いいえ。健康のために少しは外へ出かけてくれたらいいんですが。
>
> No [I don't want him to go back to work].  For the sake of his health, it'd *just* be nice if he'd go out *once in a while*.

First let's look at 出かけてくれたら here.  She'd like her husband to do something other than sit and watch TV, so going out once in a while would be a kind of favor to her.  Hence the use of てくれる here.

Second let's look at 少しは.  Here I wouldn't consider は to be a topic marker at all.  Nor would I consider it contrastive (but someone might be able to argue that point).  I'd say that it adds emphasis which is why in my translation I used the word "**just**".  There are certainly other ways to translate 少し instead of temporally as I did; I could have written "If he'd just go out a little bit" might be a bit more faithful to the Japanese.

At any rate, I hope this helps clarify your two points.